# Stardust and Candy limit

Tags: pokemon-go

I have a serial Stardust spending problem and to combat it I want to save up to about 200,000 before using it. On a similar note it won't be long before I hit 1000 Drowzee Candy.

I was wondering if there is a limit on the amount of Stardust and Candy you can have at one time?

Comment: I saw someone on Reddit with 600K+ stardust, so if there is a stardust limit it's probably very high.

Comment: where do you live to get that many Drowzees? I can only say I have almost got 1000 zubat candies :(

Comment: @Theyna Detroit

Comment: @Insane guess I'm out of luck then, stuck on the other side of the planet.  :p

Comment: @Theyna Wow that's amazing, Zubats are Pokeball eating machines. Some take me about 5 or 6 pokeballs to catch. They're so small and easy to miss for me lol

Comment: @Sync This is true

Comment: @Theyna I live in Canada, I can honestly say that there are more Drowzees here than people.

Comment: @Insane I hope it changes with the seasons or something, I'd rather have an insane amount of Eevees. Fingers crossed :)

Comment: @Sync That'd be cool but I doubt it. I think you just gotta get around to new places eventually.

Comment: @Sync plenty of Eevees in Wellington :D not an insane amount, but pretty common. And for Zubats it's all about the long throw :p

Comment: @Theyna haha lucky you. I'm guessing all the gyms near you are filled with Vaporeons. I'm getting a bit better at catching Zubats since the beginning, but sometimes my curve ball just goes right behind its tiny head.

Comment: @Insane Yeah, I'm going on vacation to Quebec this weekend, I'm hoping to find some new Pokemon there :)

Comment: @Sync so many Vaporeons....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far there has been no report about a cap on how much stardust and candy a person can have. Personally I have almost 4000 zubat candy and over 400,000 stardust. If there is a cap my best guess would be 10,000 candies and/or 1,000,000 stardust but I highly doubt there is one.

Source: Personal Experience.

Comment: Accepting this until something comes along that shows an actual limit. Possibly come back in a few days when you have 10000 Zubat candies and or if you ever make it to a million Stardust :P

Answer (score -1):

The most likely limit is 2,147,483,647 for both. It is possible that there is a limit of 32,767 for candy. Both of these limits are based on the data type they may (or may not) be using server side to store the number.

Comment: That would be the Integer or Short boundaries, but do you have proof for the candy amount to be stored as such? Also there can be an internal limit below the data type boundaries.

Comment: Well Brandon Tan managed to find the data type limit for XP so Kevin's answer could well be right!